# React Router DOM not rendering nested routes

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I have a navbar that is global i.e to be used in all pages

```
<BrowserRouter>
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<NavBar />}>
              <Route path="" element={<Home />} />
            </Route>
             <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
          </Routes>
        </BrowserRouter>
```

It is not rendering the Home component, only the Navbar when I visit /

Answer (score 1):

In this case `NavBar` is what is considered a wrapper component. For it to render any nested routes it necessarily needs to render an `Outlet` component.

[Outlet](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#outlet)

> An `<Outlet>` should be used in parent route elements to render their
> child route elements. This allows nested UI to show up when child
> routes are rendered. If the parent route matched exactly, it will
> render a child index route or nothing if there is no index route.

Example:

```
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

const NavBar = () => {
  // any business logic

  return (
    <div /* any container styling, etc... */ >
      .... navbar UI ....

      <Outlet /> // <-- nested Route components rendered here

      ....
    </div>
  );
};
```

...

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<NavBar />} >
      <Route path="" element={<Home />} /> // <-- rendered into Outlet
    </Route>
    <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```